# Why do I have TLS verification failure when trying to send mail via msmtp?

Tags: mail, tls, ssmtp

I am trying to send mail via smtp (using msmtp). The aim is to simply send via a yahoo mail account. I have configured it correctly (see bottom) so that if I run with the option `--tls-certcheck=off`, everything sends through my account. However, this is not safe. When I remove this flag, depending on what is passed as the trust file value, I get either

> msmtp: TLS certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.

or

> msmtp: cannot set X509 trust file /root/yahoo.crt for TLS session: Error while reading file.

The first occurs when the cert is within /etc/ssl/certs and the second when in /root -- even though it is the same file. I had to remove ^M characters after exporting the certificate chain from yahoo.com.
When I try to use it I get these issues? Does the certificate file name matter? I have updated the ca-certificates too (not sure if this was correct)? It seems the root cert is `DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA`, which isn't installed to my knowledge? I think it is the correct x509 format. What would the next steps be please..

The configuration for msmtp:
(note: I also set the trust file to /root/yahoo.crt and /etc/ssl/certs/yahoo.crt after I installed the file in both locations)

```
# Set default values for all following accounts.
defaults
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  
logfile        ~/.msmtp.log
#tls_certcheck off

account        yahoo
host           smtp.mail.yahoo.com
port           465
tls_starttls   off
from           <username>@yahoo.<tld>
user           <username>
password       <password>


account default: yahoo
```

Comment: You've not mentioned your OS & release details, and your configs also appear to be using a [*root*] user directory??

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and msmtp version 1.8.6. Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: forget the 2nd one. the cert in /root/ is wrong. file needs to be 600 anyways so only root is allowed to read it, not your user. the 1st one: the message seems to indicate the cert file is faulty?!